# git push force on public repository

Tags: git, repository, push

I accidently did a

> git push --force

on a public repository and reverted to previous commits. How to a fix this issue? I still have the correct versions on my local computer but not able to push them onto the github repository, it says that everything is up to date. I know this was very stupid of me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relax, if you have the commit that was the original HEAD before you overwrote it, you *can* `git push --force` it back. It's just a matter of telling it to `git` the right way.

You are getting "everything is up to date" because you are not telling it right. When that happens, it's pushing not what you think.

Find either the branch you want to re-push, or even just the commit (sha) that you want to re-push. Assuming the name of your github remote is "origin", and assuming you want to fix "master", you can push back like this:

```
git push origin the_branch:master --force
```

or even:

```
git push origin the_sha:master --force
```

But before you do that, I recommend to double-check with a diff:

```
git diff the_branch..origin/master
```

or

```
git diff the_sha..origin/master
```

or replace `diff` in the above with `rev-list` to see the list of commits that will be pushed.

Comment: Thank you. I will sleep well tonight

Comment: Sleep tight ;-) And try to avoid `--force` in the future :p